# css requires "px" on different host?

Tags: html, css

Similar to this: [When/Why Do CSS Property Values Need to Specify "px"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68340144/when-why-do-css-property-values-need-to-specify-px)

but I'm getting the error for the same property on different websites.

I've copied my website to a different host, from Dreamhost to Siteground.  The site on Dreamhost is still running, let's call it site1, and uses a subdomain, site1.example.com.  The second site on Siteground is site2, and uses a different subdomain of the parent domain, site2.example.com.

I've copied all the files across from site1 to site2, and verified it's working ok.  However, I've noticed a really odd quirk: The CSS on the new site breaks when dimensions are specified without a unit, such as `padding: 10 0;` rather than `padding: 10px 0px;`

So both websites are running simultaneously in the same browser, I've just cleared cache and cookies etc.  When I load them, the new site2 on the left breaks, and the old site1 on the right is still good.

[image]

Have checked both site1 and site2 in different browsers too, just to be sure.

On hover, it just says that it's an "invalid property value"

[image]

in Developer tools, as soon as I add "px" to each property, it works fine.

[image]

I'd like to understand why this is happening - I'm not keen on going through the whole CSS and adding units to everything.  I don't know of any way to set CSS to `require explicit` but it feels like this sort of behaviour!

Comment: Hm.  good spot, I need to check that out

Comment: !...   when I moved site2 (which is the broken one) I had spotted `<!DOCTYPE php>` was wrong and changed to `<!DOCTYPE html>` - so I've just changed it back to "php" and css is working fine again!  But "php" is incorrect, and "html" is correct!?  Putting `<!DOCTYPE html>` breaks the CSS but I'm not sure why, leaving out the units has always defaulted to "px" in other situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ***working*** website actually uses incorrect document type:

```html
<!DOCTYPE php>
```

The browser will not understand this doctype and switch to [quirks mode instead of standards mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Quirks_Mode_and_Standards_Mode).

Your CSS is also broken, it uses invalid values for margin and padding (`0 0 10 0` and `10 0 10`). In quirks mode however, these [unitless lengths](https://quirks.spec.whatwg.org/#the-unitless-length-quirk) are treated as if they are `px` values and *your website with broken CSS actually works with broken doctype*.

You need to fix both... the `DOCTYPE` and the CSS.

Comment: Darn it, so all this time it's been brokenly working 